# ¿Cómo combinar celdas usando Google Sheets API en PHP?

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

Soy nuevo en esto, estoy creando una hoja de cálculo de Google con algo de contenido usando el [API en PHP](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_multiple_ranges):

```
$id_file = "XXXXXXXXxxxxXXXXXXXXxxx"; //ID sheet
$range = "A2:E2";
$values = [["INGLÉS","ESPAÑOL","DEFINICIÓN","FUENTE","COMENTARIOS"]];
$range1 = "A1:E1";
$values1 = [["GLOSARIO"]];

$data = [];
$data1 = [];

$data[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
   'range' => $range,
   'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
   'values' => $values
]);

$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
   "valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED",
   "data" => $data

]);

$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($id_file, $requestBody);

$data1[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
   'range' => $range1,
   'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
   'values' => $values1
]);

$requestBody1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
  "valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED",
  "data" => $data1

]);

$response1 = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($id_file, $requestBody1);
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí funciona bien, pero me gustaría combinar las celdas en la primera fila y algo de formato. Me gustaría que salga de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando información e intentado agregando este código:

```
$rangel = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$rangel->setStartRowIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndRowIndex(1);
$rangel->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndColumnIndex(5);
$rangel->setSheetId(0);

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_MergeCellsRequest();
$request->setMergeType('MERGE_COLUMNS');
$request->setRange($range1);

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($request);
 $response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($id_file,$batchUpdateRequest);
```

Pero no funciona, ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Me gustaría su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para que funcione tu código debes cambiar 2 cosas:

- primero, el tipo de merge que estas haciendo, pasaría de MERGE_COLUMNS a MERGE_ALL, asi:

  ```
  $request->setMergeType('MERGE_COLUMNS');
  ```
- segundo,al setear el request debes pasarle un array indicando el tipo de request además del objeto, asi:

  ```
  $batchUpdateRequest->setRequests(['mergeCells'=>$request]);
  ```

  este detalle está especificado en la [documentación de Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#Request)